# Goto beginning of if statement?

Tags: bash, if-statement, sh

Anyway to go back to beginning of if statement if user doesn't provide correct input in bash and sh?

```
if [ "$INPUT" = "no" ]; then
    Do something
elif [ "$INPUT" = "yes" ]; then
    Do something else
else
    echo "Input not understood"
    Go back to beginning of if statement
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a loop; `bash` doesn't have a `goto` statement.

```
while true; do
  # set the value of INPUT here
  if [ "$INPUT" = "no" ]; then
    Do something
  elif [ "$INPUT" = "yes" ]; then
    Do something else
  else
    echo "Input not understood"
    continue
  fi
  break
done
```

In this "infinite" loop, we use the `continue` statement in the `else` clause to return to the top of the loop, where we do something to get a new value of `INPUT`. If we don't execute the `else` clause, we hit the `break` statement, which exits the loop.

Answer (score 2):

That's called a 'loop'.  You have `for`, `while` (and `until`) loops in shell.  Use one.  You also have `break` to exit loops and `continue` to move to the next iteration.

In this case, you don't want to go to the `if` statement; you need to get new input:

```
while read -r INPUT
do
    if [ "$INPUT" = "no" ]; then
        Do something
        break
    elif [ "$INPUT" = "yes" ]; then
        Do something else
        break
    else
        echo "Input not understood"
    fi
done
```